# How to use client with TLS in KrakenD?

Tags: go, kubernetes, api-gateway

As the title says, how do I consume an http service that requires a certificate from KrakenD?

Is it possible with KrakenD-CE? How do I implement it with KrakenD framework?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the TLS using the

```
"tls": {
    "public_key": "/etc/krakend/certs/tls.crt",
    "private_key": "/etc/krakend/certs/tls.key",
    "min_version": "TLS12",
    "max_version": "TLS13"
    }
```

based on the config **KrakenD** will work with **TLS** and handle the request.

https://www.krakend.io/docs/service-settings/tls/

Regarding implementation, it's quite simple

You can check out : https://github.com/devopsfaith/krakend-ce

Create the build using the Make

`Make build` & if you are on docker `Make docker`

Make build will provide you **executable binary** of `KrakenD API gateway` which require the config file in JSON, YAML format for API config, Rate limit and whatever config you want to set for your API.